# backslash and parentheses problem in javascript

Tags: javascript

whats the problem with backslash and parentheses in this code?
**it spesificly appears in "else if" line**

```js
function roofFix(s, x){
  if(x.includes("/")){
     var xIndex1 = x.indexOf("/");
  
    if( s[xIndex1] == " " ){
        return true
      }else{
        return false
      }
  }else if(x.includes("\")){
    if( s[xIndex1] == " " ){
        return true
      }else{
        return false
      }
  
  }else{
    return false
  }
 


}
roofFix('   h c ', '__/____')
```

Comment: The backslash has a special meaning when used in a string.

Answer (score 1):

`\` is used for escape character. If you want to compare with `\` use `\\`.

```
function roofFix(s, x){
  if(x.includes("/")){
     var xIndex1 = x.indexOf("/");

    if( s[xIndex1] == " " ){
        return true
      }else{
        return false
      }
  }else if(x.includes("\\")){
    if( s[xIndex1] == " " ){
        return true
      }else{
        return false
      }

  }else{
    return false
  }



}
roofFix('   h c ', '__/____')
```

Comment: It's generally helpful to mention at least briefly exactly what you suggest be changed.

Answer (score 1):

With the `\` you can escape special characters in a string. Right now you escape the `"` character. So add another `\` to escape the backslash character, like below. And it should work.

```js
function roofFix(s, x){
  if(x.includes("/")){
     var xIndex1 = x.indexOf("/");
  
    if( s[xIndex1] == " " ){
        return true
      }else{
        return false
      }
  }else if(x.includes("\\")){
    if( s[xIndex1] == " " ){
        return true
      }else{
        return false
      }
  
  }else{
    return false
  }
 


}
roofFix('   h c ', '__/____')
```

Comment: when i insert backslash in arguments instead of slash it should return true, but it return false!!

Comment: @emyy96 you have to use `\\\` when you call the function also.